# How does VXLAN prevent duplicate MAC addresses?

Tags: virtual-machines, mac-address, network-protocols

It seems to me that VXLAN network identifier(VNI) works silimar to a prefix keeping identical MAC addresses on different VXLAN segments separate, so that they can coexist without duplication issues.
But how is it avoided that a virtual machine generated in a host will have its MAC address different from all the others in the same VXLAN segment?